# How to solve java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.IOStatisticsSource for Pyspark in Jupyter Lab?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, jupyter-lab

I'm using:

- Jupyter Lab 3.2.9
- Spark v3.1.2
- Python 3.6.8
- Everything inside VM with Centos

I'm trying to connect to Azure Blob storage:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext, SparkConf
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType,StructField, StringType, DoubleType
import pyspark

spark = SparkSession.builder.master("local[*]") \
                    .appName("my_app") \
                    .config("spark.jars", "<PATH TO THE PROJECT ENV>env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jars/azure-data-lake-store-sdk-2.2.3.jar,<PATH TO THE PROJECT ENV>/env/lib/python3.6/site-packages/jars/hadoop-azure-3.3.1.jar") \
                    .getOrCreate()

spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.auth.type.<INFORMATION>.dfs.core.windows.net", <INFORMATION>)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth.provider.type.<INFORMATION>.dfs.core.windows.net",<INFORMATION>)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.id.<INFORMATION>.dfs.core.windows.net", <INFORMATION>)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.secret.<INFORMATION>.dfs.core.windows.net", <INFORMATION>)
spark.conf.set("fs.azure.account.oauth2.client.endpoint.<INFORMATION>.dfs.core.windows.net",<INFORMATION>)

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("Id",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Name",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("Country",StringType(),True), \
...
])

data= spark.read\
    .format("csv")\
    .option("header", True)\
    .option("nullValues", "null")\
    .schema(schema)\
    .load("abfss://<PATH>")
```

I receive the following error:

> **Py4JJavaError**: An error occurred while calling o46.load. :
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> org/apache/hadoop/fs/statistics/IOStatisticsSource
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)  at
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:756)
> at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:473)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:74)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:369)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:363)
> at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:362)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:405)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
> at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
> at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:348)
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByNameOrNull(Configuration.java:2532)
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClassByName(Configuration.java:2497)
> at org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration.getClass(Configuration.java:2593)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.getFileSystemClass(FileSystem.java:3269)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.createFileSystem(FileSystem.java:3301)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.access$200(FileSystem.java:124)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.getInternal(FileSystem.java:3352)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem$Cache.get(FileSystem.java:3320)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem.get(FileSystem.java:479)
> at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.getFileSystem(Path.java:361)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.streaming.FileStreamSink$.hasMetadata(FileStreamSink.scala:46)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.DataSource.resolveRelation(DataSource.scala:377)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.loadV1Source(DataFrameReader.scala:325)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.$anonfun$load$3(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
> at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:189)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:307)
> at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameReader.load(DataFrameReader.scala:239)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
> at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
> at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
> at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
> at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:244)
> at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
> at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:282)
> at py4j.commands.AbstractCommand.invokeMethod(AbstractCommand.java:132)
> at py4j.commands.CallCommand.execute(CallCommand.java:79)
> at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:238)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

> Caused by:
> java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.hadoop.fs.statistics.IOStatisticsSource
> at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
> at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
> at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)  ... 55 more

I'm running out of ideas. Anyone can help me?

Comment: Could you check whether you have hadoop-client-api.jar under $HADOOP_HOME\share\hadoop\client?

Comment: I have over there: hadoop-client-api-3.3.1.jar